# How do I apply a security baseline to 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security

I've setup a Windows 2008 R2 server with an Active Directory Domain Services role. I would like to apply the Specialized Security – Limited Functionality (SSLF) security baseline to it, but am unsure how to go about this.

I have downloaded and installed Security Compliance Manager tool. I think I  need to use some file from this, but am unsure which one and how to apply it to the 2008 Server. I am really new to all this so step by step guides would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the LOCAL GPO tool thats part of the kit to apply the settings to the server; after installing SCM you should see it in your Start menu under "Microsoft Security Compliance Manager\LocalGPO," or you should be able to find it in Windows Explorer at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Compliance Manager\LGPO." That part of LPT is almost identical to what was in the GPOAccelerator, you can find instructions for installing and using LPT in the SCM help content.

Before you can do that you must export/backup the relevant from the SCM tool.